# Can not check whether a JButton is clicked using NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jbutton

I am trying to create a JForm using NetBeans's Design mode and then developing it in Source mode. I have two buttons in my form and I want to check whether the `generateNumber` button is clicked or not before the `makeGuess` button performs its task. Here are the related code lines.

```
private void generateNumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                              

    private void makeGuessActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        try {
            if (!generateNumber.getModel().isPressed()) {
                throw new GameNotStartedException();
            }
        } catch (GameNotStartedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Generate a number first");
        }

    }
```

My problem is the program always falls into the `GameNotStartedException`, not matter if I click to `generateNumber` button or I do not. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the usage of `generateNumber.getModel().isPressed()` itself. This tells you if the button is currently pressed or not.

As you have it in the method `makeGuessActionPerformed` it is like this:

- You are pressing the button makeGuess
- The method `makeGuessActionPerformed` is executed
- As part of the method you check if button generateNumber is clicked (which is not true, as you clicked on button makeGuess)

You could e.g. use a boolean value to keep track of the status. The value of the boolean reflects if the button generateNumbers was already pressed.

- A click on the button generateNumbers sets the boolean value to true.
- In the method `makeGuessActionPerformed` you can check for the value of the boolean. If false, then throw the exception. Otherwise continue with your execution.

Comment: Yeah, I have already switched to that boolean method and it works fine but I wonder why that `isPressed()` method does not work.

Comment: It works imo only when the button is *currently* pressed.

Comment: I think there is a valid method for my program but I don't know what it is. Anyway, thank you for your time and interest :)